# Is there a way to allow only an Int parameter of a function within a Range

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out a way to limit an int parameter when calling a giving function as long as the int value is within a certain range.
For example:

```
class A{
    void doSomething(int nValueWithin10And214){}
}

class B{
    A objA = new A();
    objA.doSomething(int someValue)   //Here already know the limitation of the parameter
}
```

I already know to check inside the function if the parameter is within a range, but I'm looking a way when the caller already knows the limitation.

Should I create a custom throwable in these cases and the caller throws an exception when it's not within the range?

Should I create a custom object extending an Integer so the function called and the caller already comply with the requirements?

What would be the recommended way?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Document the method. Throw an exception if the parameter is unsuitable.

Comment: You could try with annotations but that won't stop you to call the method with an "invalid" `int`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way, in `Java SE`, to limit by default, your method parameter's possible values' range; however, there are some `Bean Validation` framework(s), which might help you to achieve your desired functionality. [`Hibernate's Validator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-method-constraints.html) (The Bean Validation reference implementation) is one very popular framework you can reference.

But no, no such a specification has ever been implemented to Java core language.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is by throwing an exception if the parameter is outside the range, as you mentioned yourself. Like this:

```
void doSomething(int nValueWithin10And214){
    if (nValueWithin10and214 < 10 || nValueWithin10and214 > 214 {
        throw new ValueNotInRangeException();
    }
}
```